# validate multiple checkbox in angular4

Tags: angular

can anybody tell how to validate multiple check box  user should select at least one in loading time itself .If  user didn't select check box need to show error message

Thanks

Comment: Add more details and source code, what you have implemented and what issue you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

with reactive form you can do this:

```
    form: FormGroup;

    constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.form = this.fb.group(
            {
                first: new FormControl(),
                second: new FormControl(),
                third: new FormControl(),
            },
            { validator: this.customValidator },
        );
    }

    customValidator(control: AbstractControl) {
        const first = control.get('first');
        const second = control.get('second');
        const third = control.get('third');
        return first.value || second.value || third.value ? null : 'Invalid';
    }
```

In template:

```
<div [formGroup]="form">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="first">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="second">
  <input type="checkbox" formControlName="third">
  <button [disabled]="!form.valid">Submit</button>
</div>
```